# ASP.NET Core not showing data in controls after POST with validation errors

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

**Note:** This is all very simplified code to demonstrate the problem. My real code has many more controls, client-side validation, etc.

I have the following `<form>` (very simplified) in a view named `Jim.cshtml`...

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Jim">
  <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
  <label for="Email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email">
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And the corresponding controller code...

```
public IActionResult Jim() =>
  View();

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Jim(Jim j) {
  // Silly server-side validation for testing
  if (!j.Email.StartsWith("x")) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("Email","Must start with an 'x'");
  }
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return View(j);
  }
  return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

The `Jim` view model looks like this...

```
public class Jim {
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
  public string Email { get; set; } = "";
}
```

If I load the page, enter an email that doesn't start with "j" and click the submit button, then the `ModelState` is invalid, so the controller returns the `Jim` view with the model. The validation summary shows the error message, but the textbox is empty.

I expected the textbox to be populated with the email address I entered.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: *"If I load the page and click the submit button without entering anything [...] I expected the textbox to be populated with the email address I entered."* - These two statements seem to be mutually exclusive.  Can you clarify?  Also, when you debug, does `j` contain the data you expect at all?  At what specific step is the value you expect lost?

Comment: @David You're completely right! Please see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML by itself does not know how to bind to values in your model. You have to either do it explicitly or use a tag helper like `asp-for`.

Using `asp-for`:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Email">
```

Or explicitly:

```
<input type="text" name="Email" value="@Model.Email">
```

Comment: Duh, I do feel stupid! That's so obvious! Somehow, I had got it into my head that the model binder would figure it out. Ho hum, thanks